# How to sum a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has 3 columns, start_date, end_date and a difference between them.

Start column is '2018-09-25 10:00:00', End is '2018-09-25 11:00:00', the other is a text column with the result that in this case is '01:00', but I need to sum the result in my SQL query, but it doesn't work. I've tried

```
select sum(to_timestamp(third_column)::time) as sum from my_table.
```

Comment: Sum timestamps? That makes no sense...

Comment: Actually my column is a text with the result of a subtraction between the two other columns, but I need somehow to make a sum of this column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the 3rd column, since it's derived from the first 2 anyways.

With this sample data:

```
WITH t(start_date, end_date) AS
(
                SELECT TIMESTAMP'2018-09-25 10:00', TIMESTAMP'2018-09-25 11:00'
    UNION ALL   SELECT '2018-09-25 7:00', '2018-09-25 07:45'
)
```

The following query will give you the summation of the difference between end date and start date (as an interval):

```
SELECT SUM(end_date - start_date) FROM t
```

results in the interval `01:45:00`

Comment: Thanks a lot Zack, you save me!

Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5aeca8698dfe675b21600255d89bd950)

```
SELECT 
    SUM(to_timestamp(diff, 'HH24:MI')::time) 
FROM times;
```

A: `to_timestamp()` converts text into a timestamp. The second parameter is to describe the time format (`HH24` is hours in 24h format, `MI` is minutes; https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html). Timestamp includes date part. With the `::time` cast it can be trunced.

B: `SUM()` aggregate sums up all time values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using the following should work

```
select sum(third_column::time) from data
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c91ceafce8ae7ad4026392e2b61661a4)

Comment: Actually it works partially because it returns me a result like: 

0 years 0 mons 0 days 01 hours 00 min 0.00 secs, and I just want 01:00

Comment: as shown in my demo, the sum of times does not return any year or month value ...